# HTML <table> auto expand with <img> tag

Tags: html, css

Following is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ry9Lu/

In this code, **Short Text** does not have any problem , but when **Long Text**, my `<img>` will not able to see due to `<td>` expanded over it.

The problem is because inside my `<img>` tag there is `width="95%"` style,  but this style is necessary for me, because I want to control the size of `<img>`.

Even though I apply a CSS for word break also does not help

```
p.Description
{
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

My expected result is no matter how long the text, the image will always at that size.

Please advice how should i do that.

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: currently when i have long text the image will not able to view , i want even the text is long my image are viewable just like the short text

Comment: is the solution what you wanted??

Answer (score 1):

[**i think this is what you need**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry9Lu/3/)

only css i added :

```
p#pDes {
    width:100%;
    background-color:grey; /* this is just to highlight the area */
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

**Note** : you have broken tags, though its not affecting the view, but close all `<p>`...you misplace `</p>` with `<p>`.....looks bad on html view source!